# SSH Connection Stop After Some Time But CloudFlare Tunnel Works

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a machine in my home which I use as a test machine and host some of my services, and to access those services from outside of my home I installed a CloudFlare tunnel as well.

Now after some time my server stopped responding, SSH connection showed time out, I cant access samba folders as well and cant access those services using IP addresses, but the strange part is that I can access those services using the CloudFlare tunnel URL.

However, after restarting, it worked normally but again after some time, the same thing happens

here is the output when i try to access over ssh -

```
C:\Users\Rahul>ssh -vvv rahul@192.168.1.150
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Rahul/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.150 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\Rahul/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\Rahul/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.150 [192.168.1.150] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000019DF29325A0
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.150 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.150 port 22: Connection timed out
```

My SSH Config file looks like -

```
Host 192.168.1.150
HostName 192.168.1.150
User rahul
```